# Line break with valueGetter in Ag-Grid

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ag-grid, line-breaks

I'm using ag-Grid and displaying 2 data in 1 cell. I used to display it via the `cellRenderer` and in between data i use `'<br/>'` to break line and that worked perfectly.

```
{headerName: 'ShortName \n Name', cellRenderer: function(params){  return   params.data.INSTRSHORTNAME + '<br/>' + params.data.INSTRNAME },width:250, resizable:true, sortable: false} ,
```

However, when i decided to export the grid to a `csv` file the values where i used `cellRenderer` don't show up because i have to use to `valueGetter` to make them exported. My problem is that when i use `valueGetter` i don't know how to add a break line between data in the cell.

```
{headerName: 'ShortName \n Name', valueGetter: function(params){  return   params.data.INSTRSHORTNAME + '\n' + params.data.INSTRNAME },width:250, resizable:true, sortable: false} ,
```

Any idea how can i use a break line with `valueGetter` ?

Thank you.